# Perform a task on Azure batch

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-batch

I am new to Azure batch. I have to perform a task on nodes in the pool.

The approach I am using is that I have the code that I want to run on the node. I am making a zip of the jar of the .class file and uploading to my Azure storage account and then getting the application Id and putting it in ApplicationPackageReference and adding to my task in job.

```
String applicationId= "TaskPerformApplicationPack";
ApplicationPackageReference reference = new ApplicationPackageReference().withApplicationId(applicationId);
List<ApplicationPackageReference> list = new ArrayList<ApplicationPackageReference>();
list.add(reference);
TaskAddParameter taskToAdd = new TaskAddParameter().withId("mytask2").withApplicationPackageReferences(list);
taskToAdd.withCommandLine(String.format("java -jar task.jar"));


batchClient.taskOperations().createTask(jobId, taskToAdd);
```

Now when I run this, my task fails giving an error that

> access for one of the specified Azure Blob(s) is denied

How can I run a particular code on a node using azure batch job tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good place to start is: (*I have covered most of the helpful links along with the guided docs below, they will elaborate the use of environment level variable etc, also I have included few sample links as well.*) hope material and sample below will help you. `:)`

Also I would recommend to recreate your pool if it is old which will ensure you have the node running at the latest version.

- [Azure batch learning path](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/batch/):
- [Samples & demo link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples) or look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/ArticleProjects/ParallelTasks/Program.cs)
- [Detailed walk through depending on what you are using i.e. `CloudServiceConfiguration` or `VirtualMachineConfiguration` link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages)

Further to add from the article: also look in here: [Application Packages with VM configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065950/application-packages-with-vm-configuration)

In particular [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages) link will take you through the guide process of how to use it in your code: Also be it resource file or package you need to make sure that they are uploaded and available for use at the batch level.

along with sample like: (below is a pool level pkg example)

```
// Create the unbound CloudPool
CloudPool myCloudPool =
    batchClient.PoolOperations.CreatePool(
        poolId: "myPool",
        targetDedicatedComputeNodes: 1,
        virtualMachineSize: "small",
        cloudServiceConfiguration: new CloudServiceConfiguration(osFamily: "4"));

// Specify the application and version to install on the compute nodes
myCloudPool.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List<ApplicationPackageReference>
{
    new ApplicationPackageReference {
        ApplicationId = "litware",
        Version = "1.1" }
};

// Commit the pool so that it's created in the Batch service. As the nodes join
// the pool, the specified application package is installed on each.
await myCloudPool.CommitAsync();
```

For the Task level form the link above a sample is: (make sure you have followed the steps correctly mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages).

```
CloudTask task =
    new CloudTask(
        "litwaretask001",
        "cmd /c %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_LITWARE%\\litware.exe -args -here");

task.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List<ApplicationPackageReference>
{
    new ApplicationPackageReference
    {
        ApplicationId = "litware",
        Version = "1.1"
    }
};
```

further to add: be it `CloudServiceCOhnfiguration` or `VirtualMachineConfiguration`, An application package is `**a .zip file**` that contains the application binaries and supporting files that are required for your tasks to run the application. Each application package represents a specific version of the application. from reference: [4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages)

I gave it a shot and tried and was successful, so I am not able to replicate the error above and seems like you might be missing something.